# Is it okay for “String.prototype.search” to have a string argument?

Tags: javascript

[The MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) says the single parameter of “String.prototype.search” is a regular expression object, `RegExp`. But seemingly I can feed it a `string` as well in my Chrome 75; and it works. Is this a Chrome-specific behavior, or *the standard* I can rely on?

```js
console.log("ABCDEF".search(/BCD/)); // 1 // Good
console.log("ABCDEF".search("BCD")); // 1 // Good?
```

Comment: This shoud work in any browser. [That same article says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search#Parameters): "_If a non-RegExp object `obj` is passed, it is implicitly converted to a RegExp by using new RegExp(obj)_".

Comment: @Teemu Oh. Somehow I overlooked that sentence. Thanks.

Comment: I feel like these kind of questions shouldn't be asked. With a little bit of effort and some more research you could find out yourself. You could look at the source code for example. (didnt downvote btw)

Comment: I’m sorry for asking a minor question, I understood. Should I close this question as off-topic? What do I do for this mistake?

Comment: Of course, if you want to search for a string (without interpreting it as a regex), then you should use `indexOf` or `includes`